# Create a VLAN on HP Procurve switches

Tags: hp, vlan

New to this site, but it's pretty darn great, so I won't be a stranger here!

Still a n00b though :-)

Need a walkthrough on howto create a VLAN.

I have the ipadress space for the VLAN
I have the subnett for the VLAN

What I don't know is how to go about creating a VLAN. Can anyone advice me? Where, when, how?

Thanks in advance!

Maclovin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all. IP adressess/subnet are not related to a VLAN, it's a Layer2 protocol (below TCP/IP and such wich is a Layer3 protocol).

There are several ways of setting up vlan on a Procurve switch:

- The Web interface
- The builtin menu via CLI (conf t and then setup)
- CLI

Most admins out there come from a Cisco-regulated world, so they always use CLI (like I do).

Example VLAN configuration via CLI (remember, conf t first)

```
vlan 1234
 name "McLovin's super VLAN"
 untagged 5-8,12
 tagged 24
 exit
```

Explainations:

- vlan = the VLAN ID
- name = something descriptive so you know what this VLAN is used for
- untagged = the untagged ports for normal network clients (PC's, servers  etc)
- tagged = the tagged ports for other switches to pass on VLAN traffic

I strongly advise you to pick up the manual/documentation for your switch and start reading - or hire a network consultant to train you on how this works. And please - test this before deploying out to your clients.

Comment: And as the honorary Dr. John D. Zoidberg would have said: That just raises further questions.. Open your mouth, I want to take a look at that brain of yours.

I have a wlan controller and som AP-boxes.
 
40 kilometers from here I have a switch. It is of course connected to other switches.

How do I go about creating Vlans for that particular switch, and to the headquarters?

I have a management vlan (which is the new one I am creating) predefined vlan 811, and 2 other VLans.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Oh boy. This is a bit difficult to explain, as it requires VLAN configuration at many different places. It all depends on your network setup. Do you have a trunked VLAN connection between the locations or is this over VPN (with firewalls)? I suggest you call whoever provided the link between your offices and ask them to set it up.

Comment: Great answer Pauska, @mclovin I suggest you start a different question along the lines of "How should I design my network and vlan setup given x, y and x that are already in place" as the two requirements are very different and we always like to ask and answer questions on this site that will benefit more people than those actually asking it if you know what I mean.

Comment: Come to think of it, I have moved on :-) It helps actually sitting my ass down, working with switches, and at the same time read about it. Thanks for all help!